# A question on Schwartz distributions

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fa.functional-analysis

I have a question on the tempered distributions, namely, continous functionals  on Schwartz class endowed with the weak* topology. Is is a Barreled space, say, a space whose convex, balanced, absorbing and closed subsets are neighborhood of the origin?

Comment: The space of tempered distributions with its strong topology is barrelled, but not with the weak* topology: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrelled_space (see Properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the weak$^*$ dual of a locally convex space $X$ is barrelled then the bounded sets of $X$ are finite dimensional (because the polar of a bounded set $B$ is a barrel which then contains the polar of a finite set $E$ and
the theorem of bipolars implies that $B$ is contained in the absolutely convex hull of $E$). For Frechet spaces (like the Schwartz space) this implies that $X$ is finite dimensional.